# Dovecot autoresponder with vmail

Tags: postfix, dovecot, sieve

I have server with postfix and dovecot. E-Mails are delivered with dovecot. `/etc/postfix/master.cf` looks like this:

```
dovecot   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail:vmail argv=/usr/bin/spamc -e /usr/libexec/dovecot/dovecot-lda -f ${sender} -d ${user}@${nexthop}
```

I have address that is not valid.

If someone write email there, I want so send autoresponce there and to forward the email to someone else.

I did forwarding with `/etc/postfix/virtual`:

```
vess@trabels.net    vess@trabels.net, ticket@trabels.net
```

However I don't know how to use autoresponder sieve:

```
require ["fileinto", "vacation"];

vacation
    # Reply at most once a day to a same sender
    :days 1
    :subject "Out of office reply"
    # List of additional recipient addresses which are included in the auto replying.
    # If a mail's recipient is not the envelope recipient and it's not on this list,
    # no vacation reply is sent for it.
    :addresses []
"
Hello,
I will be out of the office till Monday, 29 January with no access to the e-mail.
Please write to ticket@trabels.net.
";
```

Using `/etc/postfix/virtual` somehow will be best, e.g. something like:

```
vess@trabels.net    vess@trabels.net, ticket@trabels.net, autorespond
```

Comment: Responding to non-existent email addresses is not a good idea, spammers will try random addresses (with fake sender addresses) and these are all answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it was very easy as soon as I realized that sieve commands are like functions in programming language, except there are no brackets.

I come up with this:

```
require ["fileinto", "vacation"];

if header :contains "X-Spam-Flag" "YES" {
    fileinto "Junk";

}elsif address :is "to" "vess@trabels.net" {
    vacation "I will be out of the office till Monday.";

}
```